# Howto let Primefaces work with @ConversationScoped Beans?

Tags: jsf, tomcat, primefaces, cdi, myfaces

I build a short page with JSF-Compnents which displays and increments a value from a @ConversationScoped Bean. This page is able to end the Conversation and is getting a new Bean after ending the old Conversation. Here is what it looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head />
<h:body>
    <h:form>
      <h:outputText id="i" value="#{test.i}" />
      <h:commandButton value="increment" 
         actionListener="#{test.increment}" 
         update="i cid" />
      <h:outputText id="cid" 
         value="#{javax.enterprise.context.conversation.id}" />
      <h:commandButton value="end"
         actionListener="#{test.endConversation}"
         update="i cid" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The code for the Bean is quite simple:

```
package de.burghard.britzke.test.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.Conversation;
import javax.enterprise.context.ConversationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class Test implements Serializable {

   @Inject Conversation conversation;
   private int i;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() { 
      conversation.begin(); 
      System.out.println("init conversation"+conversation.getId());
   }

   public int getI() {   return i; }
   public void setI(int i) { this.i = i; }

   public void increment() { i++;System.out.println(i); }

   public void endConversation() {
      System.out.println("ending conversation "+conversation.getId());
      conversation.end();
   }
}
```

Everything works well, when using the standard **h:commandButton** Components. But using the Primefaces Components **p:commandButton** then every click on the 'increment' Button grabs a new Bean instance because the cid-Parameter is not passed to the Server. It has been stated that this is not a primefaces issue. But why is it working with the standard components and not with the primefaces ones?
I have been able to pass the cid-Parameter by explicitely embedding a **f:param** component into the commandButton Components but after destroying the Conversation the parameter is sent with no value producing an error. But it should even work without the **f:param** component.

Is there a short tutorial how to work with Primefaces and Conversation scoped beans (without explicitely passing the cid-Parameter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the `f:param` in case of ended conversation has been that the param should not be passed with invalid values (null) for the parameter `cid`. So correcting this with the following code worked well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head />
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <h:outputText value="#{test.i}" />
        <p:commandButton value="increment"
            actionListener="#{test.increment}"
            update="@parent">
            <f:param 
                name="#{not empty javax.enterprise.context.conversation.id?'cid':''}"
                value="#{javax.enterprise.context.conversation.id}" />
        </p:commandButton>
        <h:outputText
            value="#{javax.enterprise.context.conversation.id}" />
        <p:commandButton value="end" actionListener="#{test.endConversation}"
            update="@parent">
            <f:param name="cid" value="#{javax.enterprise.context.conversation.id}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

But I would like the primefaces components to do the conversation handling without the need for page programmers to explicitly pass a `f:param`. They should behave like standard JSF (MyFaces) components do.

Answer (score 0):

One significant difference between `<h:commandButton>` and `<p:commandButton>` is that the PrimeFaces variety uses AJAX by default. You seem to know this on some level since you've been tweaking the `update` parameter of `<p:commandbutton>` to get the view to update.

With that in mind, I'm guessing you'd have the same problem if you used `<f:ajax>` yourself with a regular `<h:commandButton>`, which would indicate that it's not specifically a PrimeFaces problem.

As to your actual problem, I can't say for sure, but I have run into issues with starting a conversation in the same request that establishes the session. To test this, you can try either starting on a separate page that links to this test page or, instead of your `@PostConstruct` method, put this at the beginning of your `increment()` method:

```
if (conversation.isTransient()) {
    conversation.begin();
}
```

I know this doesn't fix your problem, but maybe it gives you enough information to work around it.